# Getting comprehensive list of Rules expression operators

Tags: qgis, style, vector

I'm selecting and styling my points layer on a contour map of Philadelphia using Rules Based Styling. The filtering process using [string_field = 'string'] turns out not to be accurate for one of my three rules.  I have 'Homocide - Justifiable'  and it returns points with (at least) 'Thefts'.

I'd like to try another expression.  In any case it would be nice to have a list of all the possible expressions.

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 4):

The full function reference is available directly in the query builder:

[image]